# Group json data by partial key

Tags: python

I'm having a json - json_obj  - with the following form:

```
[
{
    "uuid": "946684800 - Berlin Marzahn",
    "lat": 52.54,
    "lon": 13.54,
    "timestamp": 946684800,
    "temp": -0.57,
    "feels_like": -2.64,
    "humidity": 97,
    "pressure": 1024,
    "station": "Berlin Marzahn"
},
{
    "uuid": "946688400 - Berlin Marzahn",
    "lat": 52.54,
    "lon": 13.54,
    "timestamp": 946688400,
    "temp": -0.38,
    "feels_like": -2.46,
    "humidity": 97,
    "pressure": 1024,
    "station": "Berlin Marzahn"
},
{
    "uuid": "946692000 - Berlin Marzahn",
    "lat": 52.54,
    "lon": 13.54,
    "timestamp": 946692000,
    "temp": -0.42,
    "feels_like": -2.6,
    "humidity": 97,
    "pressure": 1025,
    "station": "Berlin Marzahn"
},...
]
```

The following Code snippet groups the json_obj by month:

```
   month_data = defaultdict(list)

   for json_obj in d:
      timestamp = json_obj["timestamp"]
      dt_obj = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
     json_obj["timestamp"] = dt_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
     
     month_data[dt_obj.strftime("%Y-%m")].append(json_obj)
```

What I dont understand is, how the magic happens in the last line. How does it happen, that only the json_obj for a specific month end up in the dictionary?

Thank you for any explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because a dictionary can't have two key's with the same value.

example:

09-12-2021 ; 09-20-2021 ; 09-03-2021

will be stored in : month_data["2021-09"]

hope I understood your question.

Comment: that answers my question.  That was my missing link. So attempting to use the same key again will just overwrite the previous value stored and keeps adding to the same dictionary keeping the values already present, right?

Comment: Yes. Remember this it comes really hand in some cases.

Comment: Very handy indeed, I never used it like that before, knowing of course about the keys nature. nifty approach... ;)

Answer (score 1):

The magic comes from `defaultdict`

`month_data` is a `defaultdict(list)`

It means that you dont need to check if there is a key before you try and append to the value (a `list` in this example). The `defaultdict` will make sure to create an empty list and append what you want to append.

```
{'t1': [d1,d2,d34,d78],'t2': [d11,d22,d344,d758]}
```

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for more.

Comment: sure, that one I understand, but how does it groups the json_data entries into one dict with the key (dt_obj.strftime("%Y-%m")) - I'm missing the grouping feature somehow

Comment: Your dict key is `dt_obj.strftime("%Y-%m")` and your dict value is a list. The data is collected into a list per timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is nothing more than a collection is key-value pairs.

You are creating a dictionary using `defaultdict(list)`, which happens to insert a new element of type `list` each time you access a key that does not exist.

Now, the grouping works because your key is the year-month part of the date:

```
dt_obj.strftime("%Y-%m")
```

For instance:

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.now()
print(date.strftime("%Y-%m"))
```

prints:

```
2021-12
```

So each object whose date is in december will end up in the list with the key `2021-12`.